# Intuition behind the Sum Theorem in dimension theory

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

In the Menger-Urysohn dimension, for any two subspaces $A, B$ of $X$, there is
$$
\operatorname{dim}(A\cup B)\leqslant \operatorname{dim}(A)+\operatorname{dim}(B)+1
$$
However, if $A, B$ are closed subspaces with $\operatorname{dim}(A)\leqslant n$ and $\operatorname{dim}(B)\leqslant n$, then
$$
\operatorname{dim}(A\cup B)\leqslant n
$$
This is part of the Sum Theory in dimension theory. I wonder what is the intuition behind this fact. Why do closed sets not increase dimension?

Comment: The classical Menger-Urysohn formula says $\dim (A\cup B)\le \dim (A)+\dim(B)+1$.

Comment: Maybe Hurewicz and Wallman use the $+$ sign to indicate union?  That used to be the notation in older papers.